# How to write UI manual test case for longer webpage?

Tags: user-interface, testcase, ui-testing, gui-testing

I'm to write UI test case for the homepage for a web application. the home page is very long. How to write Manual UI test cases for the home page? It's for http://www.jarviz.com 
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I just wanted to see UI test case for a home page or any web page(ex: google login page, anything) so that I'll know how it is actually written. I don't care how long the web page is.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to divide web page to separate section/parts like a) Main Menu, b) Login/Sign Up, c) Make Your Move section d) Your applications, our platform etc.

2) Then for each part try to exclude single element. For example Main Menu button, or Login button, or Top Banner Control buttons.

3) Then write test cases for each element and action that you can do with the element.

Simple example:
Title: Pressing of the Main Menu button; Precondition: Web page should be opened; Steps to reproduce: Click on Main Menu button; Expected Result: Side Main Menu should be presented on the screen; Actual result: the same - Side Main Menu should be presented on the screen.

Try to use Google Sheets for your test cases.